# Java 17 InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}")

Tags: java, spring

I have an issue after trying to migrate a microservice from Java 11 to Java 17. When I try to run the application, I get this error: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private volatile java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent.atomic" to unnamed module @3b0fe47a

The problem is that I do not have Atomic or volatile variables in my code. The error seems to be from a repository interface, I will post it below, along with the entity classes associated.

```
public interface EventServiceRepository extends ReactiveAerospikeRepository<EventDocument, String>, RepositoryConfiguration {

    @Override
    default Flux<EventDocument> findAll() {
        return Flux.error(new UnsupportedOperationException("Usage of getAll is forbidden."));
    }

    default Mono<EventDocument> saveWithCas(EventDocument eventDocument) {
        return CasUtils.toOptimisticRetryable(this.saveWithErrorHandling(eventDocument), getMaxCasRetries());
    }

    default Mono<EventDocument> updateWithCas(String id,
                                              Mono<EventDocument> switchIfEmpty,
                                              Function<EventDocument, Mono<EventDocument>> updateFunction) {

        var userDocumentMono = findById(id);
        return CasUtils.toOptimisticRetryable(
                userDocumentMono
                        .switchIfEmpty(switchIfEmpty)
                        .flatMap(updateFunction)
                        .flatMap(this::saveWithErrorHandling),
                getMaxCasRetries()
        );
    }


    default Mono<EventDocument> saveWithErrorHandling(EventDocument document){
        try {
            return save(document);
        }catch (Exception exception){
            return Mono.error(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class EventDocument {

    @Id
    private String userId;

    private EventConfig eventConfig;

    @Expiration(unixTime = true)
    private Long expiration;

    @Version
    private long version;

    private Long fetchTimestamp;

    private Integer userClubRank;
}
```

```
@Setter
@Valid
public class EventConfig extends AbstractCombinableConfig<EventConfig> implements ConfigCombiningStrategy<EventConfig> {

    public final static String FEATURE_NAME = "Event";

    private Long eventId;

    private String eventName;

    private EventType eventType;

    private Boolean enabled;

    private Boolean configStickyByClub;

    private Integer userClubRank;

    private Long bucketNo;

    private String correlationId;

    private Long currencyId;

    private List<EventsPeriods> eventsPeriods;

    @JsonDeserialize(as = TreeMap.class)
    private NavigableMap<Integer, Triggers> triggersPerClubRank;

    private Double sinkShopCycleMultiplier;
    private Double sinkShopSliceMultiplier;
    private Long sinkShopSlice;

    private Map<String, Long> progressionMaxValueBaseAmount;
    private Map<String, Long> progressionRewardBaseAmount;
    private Map<String, Long> progressionCapBaseAmount;

    private Map<String, Progression> progressions;
    private Map<String, RecurrentTrigger> recurrentTriggers;

    private Double rewardMultiplier;
    private Map<String, Reward> rewards;
    private Map<String, Object> properties;
}
```

The more specific error given is this: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventServiceRepository' defined in EventServiceRepository defined in @EnableReactiveAerospikeRepositories declared on AerospikeConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is ... ( above error )

The weird thing is that I do not have any volatile atomic variable in my entire code.
Does anyone know how this can be fixed?
I also tried the solution with starting the project with the arguments "java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED", but it did not work.